# Search by transaction id in transaction set in R

Tags: r, apriori, arules

I am working on a marketbasket analysis with *arules in R*, my transaction set has transaction id, like in the example.

screen shot of example:

[image]

I have a need to search items in the transaction set by transaction id, 
like, if I search for `0002`, it should list out all the item related to that transaction id.

Comment: in what format is your data? how did you load it into R? is it  a json, csv, data.frame , list etc?

Comment: the data is in transaction set format in r, I loaded the data in R, using the syntax below :trans1<-as(split(trans[,"item"],trans[,"Transaction ID"]),"transactions")

Comment: you example doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understood you correctly, **and** trans1 is a transaction object, you can try:

(Grep will get you all transactions containing the string)

```
inspect(trans1[grep("0002",trans1@itemsetInfo$transactionID)])
```

update:
To get exact match try:

```
 inspect(trans1[ trans1@itemsetInfo$transactionID=='0002',])
```

Comment: thank you,  this is quite close, only issues I face with this is that , it also pulls transactionID's 00021, 00022 & 00023

Comment: Try: inspect(trans1[grep("0002$",trans1@itemsetInfo$transactionID)]) The dollarsign means end of line But the second one Zahiro mentioned would also work